# Show Data values on a boxplot with metric and nominal Data

Tags: r, boxplot

I have a Dataframe of Apartment Rental offers with these Variables:
baseRent: Metric Variable of the monthly Price
balcony: Nominal Variable of True or False if the Apartment has an Balcony

I want to see where the Median, Mean and the Quantiles are of Apartments with Balkony vs. Apartments without Balkony.

I made a Boxplot, to show the Difference between Apartments with Balcony and without Balcony, but the Boxplot does not show detailed Values of the Median or Quantiles.

```
ggplot(df, aes(y = baseRent, x = balcony)) +
  geom_boxplot()
```

How can i generate the Values Mean, Median, 1.Quantile and so of my Model of Apartments with baseRent and balcony?

I tried with a model and Summary function like this:

```
balconymodel <- lm(baseRent ~ balcony, data=df)
summary(balconymodel)
```

But the Output just shows the Correlation...

Comment: Could you please share some reproducible data using `dput`?

Answer (score 0):

I found the Solution.

The Function favstats() shows the Values I needed. With my Data its:

```
favstats(baseRent ~ balcony, data=df)
```

Comment: To clarify, this is from the mosaic package?